# how to edit file contents(numbers) by java?

Tags: java

i want to edit the text file contents while i'm adding contents of students

```
              *scoreboard*
 students :4 people
 blah blah
```

to

```
              *scoreboard*
 students :21 people
 blah blah
```

regardless of number of the people

ex)

```
students :9 people ->  students :13 people
students :4 people ->  students :21 people
```

this code is adding contents. (contents of blah blah)
and additionally i want to edit count of students (increased count of students)
**the important thing is to sense number of the student.**
i have no clue about it

```java
String addmessage ="";
for(a=0;a<haksu;a++)    
{
    addmessage +="" + String.format("%10s",ab[a].hakb) + String.format("%10s",ab[a].n) + String.format("%12d",ab[a].g) + String.format("%12d",ab[a].s) + String.format("%12d",ab[a].y) + String.format("%12d",ab[a].sa)+ String.format("%12d",ab[a].sc) + String.format("%12d",ab[a].c) + String.format("%12.1f",ab[a].p) +"      "+ ab[a].h + "\n";

}
try {
    BufferedWriter bwrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
    bwrite.write(addmessage + "\n");
    bwrite.close();
}
finally {

}
filereader = new FileReader(file);
bufReader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
line = "";
while((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
bufReader.close();
```

Comment: And what is the question here? What problems are you facing?

Comment: If you already have the code to write the full file and the file is not overly long, one simple solution would be to simply write the full file content again.

Comment: load whole file to a list of string, one entry per line, for each line string.replace, write back to file

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a file in place is rather difficult, in particular if the size of certain fields change. Given that your file does not seem to be too long, an easier solution is to read the file completely into memory and then write out the modified content over the original file.